# How to redirect a multipart-formdata request to another server, using GraphQL?

Tags: java, node.js, graphql

I have a React app that connects to a mock Nodejs server during development and connects to a Java server when on prod.

The idea here was to just create a GraphQL server on Nodejs, in order to avoid having to depend on our backends devs. In other words, we re-created all our Postgres tables and managed to get GraphQL up and running. Querying the db works just fine, for both queries and for mutations.

The problem here is that we need to sometimes upload files. With Nodejs/Express/Fastify, we had multer (for our mock server for development) and for prod, our Java devs did their part to mirror the same behavior. The decision, for now, was made to somehow hit our new GraphQL endpoint with the multipart-formdata and somehow redirect the request, with the formdata, to the Java backend, which we will leave up and running for now.

The only requests that the Java backend will handle are those, that require uploads. For such a use case, we need to somehow hit it/redirect to it.

Is this possible? I've looked pretty extensively, I couldn't find anything online. Perhaps someone here has figured this out in the past.

Comment: Perhaps you could just add a middleware before your route handlers which checks if the `Content-Type` header is `multipart/form-data` and does the redirect?

Comment: Interesting, I think adding the middleware or just a HoF wouldn't be a problem, but how, exactly, would I make the redirect.

Comment: That probably depends on which library or framework you're using for GraphQL, or rather whatever handles the HTTP part.

Comment: Well, even if we use fetch or axios, is the main idea here to upload the files to the GraphQL server locally, then re-create the form data and create a new request to the Java backend? Is creating a redirect impossible?